# Map JSON string property to ES object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I have a process that imports some of the data from external sources to elasticsearch. I use C# and NEST client.
Some of the classes have string properties that contain JSON. Same property may contain different json schema depending on source.
I want to index and analyze json objects in these properties.

I tried object type mapping using  [ElasticProperty(Type=FieldType.Object)] but it doesn't seem to help.

What is the right way to index and analyze these strings? 
E.g. I import objects like below and then want to query all start events of customer 9876 that have status rejected. I then want to see how they distribute over period of time  (using kibana).

```
var e = new Event (){id=123, source="test-log" input="{type:'START',params:[{name:'customerid',value:'9876'},{name:'region',value:'EU'}]}",result="{status:'rejected'}"};
```

Comment: How would you like to query these documents in elasticsearch?

Comment: I want to search and visualize in kibana. E.g. some of the json objects have arrays of properties one of which is customer id or email address. I want to be able to see how specific events distribute over time for specific customers.

Comment: In Splunk I have Extract Field feature that allows me to index any of the inner properties that are part of the strings collected from log files